# How come my jquery plugin is not working on my page but in the very similair sample code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the [sample code](http://dev.resihop.nu/ui.demo.html) The javascript drowdown works fine, but on [link text](http://dev.resihop.nu) my page it doesn't work in firefox.
**sample code**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>geo-autocomplete demos</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.geo_autocomplete.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$().ready(function() {
$('.from').geo_autocomplete();
});
</script> 

<style type="text/css"> 
.ui-autocomplete { overflow-y: auto; width:300px; }
* html .ui-autocomplete { /* IE max- */height: expression( this.scrollHeight > 320 ? "320px" : "auto" ); }
.ui-autocomplete { max-height: 320px; }
.ui-autocomplete li { font-size:10pt; }
</style> 
</head> 
<body> 
<h1>geo-autocomplete demos</h1> 
<h3>Basic use</h3> 
<p>Location: <input type="text" class="from" size="50" /></p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

**Some of the javascript from my implementation(not working):**

**from my header**

```
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
            <script src="/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.geo_autocomplete.js"></script>
            <script src="/js/common-2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**common-2.0.js**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
        //Some other code, removed in this example

    $('.from, .to').geo_autocomplete();
});
```

Comment: what should happen in the sample code? I don't see anything in the link

Comment: ok autocomplete happens while writing the 2nd word

Comment: js errors in your link text page `Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Operation is not supported"  code: "9" nsresult: "0x80530009 (NS_ERROR_DOM_NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR)"  location: "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false Line: 9"]
Source File: http://dev.resihop.nu/js/ui.geo_autocomplete.js
Line: 16` and `Error: google.maps.Geocoder is not a constructor
Source File: http://dev.resihop.nu/js/ui.geo_autocomplete.js
Line: 16`

Comment: I suppose the problem is related to xsl transformation of your page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me as if your page is not successfully getting all the Google Javascript files it needs. There are errors in the console. It's hard to tell exactly what's wrong because Firebug seems confused by the fact that your page is XML.